# Displaying error msg that the user entered the wrong password

Tags: django, authentication, httprequest, validationerror

I am trying to write a page for a user to update their information and change their password.

I have it working now. The code that I have provided works, but I do not know how to tell the user they entered the wrong password. If the user enters a password the form is valid but if they enter the wrong password I want to say the form is not valid. But if I put forms.ValidationError("some error msg") in the else stmt that right now says forms.errors, it doesn't go back to the template but displays the error msg in a compiler msg page.

This is my 
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
def edit_page(request):

u = request.user

if request.method == 'POST':

    form = EditUserForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        if u.check_password(form.cleaned_data['oldPassword']):

            u.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])

            u.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')    

        else:

            form.errors //Where I put forms.ValidationError()   

else:

    form = EditUserForm()

variables = RequestContext(request, {

    'form': form, 'user': request.user

})      

return render_to_response(

    'registration/Edit_User.html',

    variables

)
```

This is in my forms.pyclass

```
EditUserForm(forms.Form):

oldPassword = forms.CharField(
    label=u'Current Password',
    widget = forms.PasswordInput()
)   
password1 = forms.CharField(
    label=u'New Password',
    widget=forms.PasswordInput()
)
password2 = forms.CharField(
    label=u'New Password (Again)',
    widget=forms.PasswordInput()
)

def clean_password2(self):
    if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data:
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 == password2:
            return password2
    raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')
```

Comment: Do you have Method="POST" in your html form?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `clean_oldPassword` method. You call `check_password` on the *string* 'oldPassword', instead of the variable, so naturally it fails.

You should also ensure that your template displays `form.errors`, so you can see why it doesn't validate.

Comment: I changed it to what you suggested and it still does nothing but takes me back to the editing user info page. I put in some print statements and it is not passing the form.isValid() if statement. Also It used to tell you what was wrong like if the passwords did not match but now it does nothing. Also I do have from.erros in my template.